# How does SharePoint 2013 get the document name when checking in / uploading into a library?

Tags: 2013, document, versioning, check-in

I wanted to know, how SharePoint gets the name of a document when checking it in or uploading it to any document library. How can I imagine this architecture? I'm asking myself this question, because I am curious how SharePoint knows, that when a document already exists in a library it gives a new higher version number to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all Web applications, when you upload a document, the file name is posted to the server along with the file content.
SharePoint gets the file name, and checks in the SQL content DB if a file with the same name exists in the same location. If it finds one, there's two options:

1. Either the library is configured for versioning (this is checked again with a SQL query on the content DB): in that case, a new version is pushed into the DB.
2. Or the library is not set for versioning: in that case, an error is displayed to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. One more little question: Can one talk about a certain component (if so, whats the name of it?), which task is to compare the file name of an uploaded document with file names in the DB - or in other words, which can "read" the name of a document and compare it to others?

Comment: That's a very simple task, coded in the DLLs/stored procedures of SharePoint. There's no real "component" for such a task. It's simply part of the core SharePoint code.